# How to store class objects in a list in android?

Tags: java, android

In android if I have an activity class called MyActivityA.java and MyActivityB.java, and both of them have a method called `restart()`, how can I store MyActivityA.this, and MyActivityB.this objects in a list? What kind of object would the list be declared with?

Also how would I loop through those elements in that list and call the `restart()` method for each item?

Thanks.

Comment: Before you try to go down this path, why?  Trying to store a reference to an Activity outside of an Activity is a really bad idea.  What are you trying to achieve?  Why do you want to restart? Reading this and your previous question, I thoroughly recommend that you learn the Activity life cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create an interface for abstracting the `restart()`:

```
    public interface Restarable {
        void restart();
    }
```

Let `MyActivityA` and `MyActivityB` implement `Restartable` interface.

```
    public class MyActivityA extends Activity implements Restartable {
        @Override
        public void restart() {
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
```

Then you can create a list of `Restartable`, add `MyActivityA.this` and `MyActivityB.this` and loop through the list to call `restart()`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply create a list of Objects, something like this:

```
List<Object> objList = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

and then add the objects of your classes like this:

```
objList.add(obj);
```

Comment: I was thinking that, which will work for storing the objects, but when I loop through them, how would I call the restart method on a `Object` object. Eclipse will complain because the `Object` object doesn't have a method called `restart()`, and I wouldn't know what to cast it to.

Comment: @omega You can always cast the object to your Activity class and then call the restart method. Also you can check what kind(which activity) of object it is by using instanceOf .

Comment: Can you should be code for how I would loop through the array and call the restart method on each, Im not sure what you mean. If I use instance of, don't I need to check for every type of instance?

Answer (score 1):

> In android if I have an activity class called MyActivityA.java and
>   MyActivityB.java, and both of them have a method called restart(), how
>   can I store MyActivityA.this, and MyActivityB.this objects in a list?

Just make an Interface like "Restartable" and define a method `restart()`.

Let both of your classes implement this interface. Now you can make a `List<Restartable> list` to store all of your objects.
To restart them all use an for-each-loop an call the method `.restart()`

```
for(Restarteble obj: list){
  obj.restart();
}
```